# inferred type arguments error in graph class in scala

Tags: scala

I try to implement the following graph class in scala:
    case class NodeT

```
case class Node[T](i:T)

class Graph[N<:Node[T], +T](someNodes:Set[N], val edges:Set[(N,N)]) {
  val nodes: Set[N] = someNodes ++ edges.map(_._1) ++ edges.map(_._2)

  def addVortex(node:N)=new Graph(someNodes, edges)//just use someNodes instead of nodes + node
}
```

But there is an error saying

> inferred type arguments [N,Nothing] do not conform to class Graph's
>   type parameter bounds [N <: Node[T],+T]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just clarify @chengpohi's answer

There are two issues in your code.

Small issue: since type `T` is not mentioned in the `Graph` constructor, you should specify it directly like:

```
def addVertex(node: N) = new Graph[N, T](someNodes + node, edges)
```

Bigger issue: as @chengpohi mentioned type `T` could not be covaiant in `Graph` and invariant in `Node` simultaneously. So you should correct one of the definitions

```
case class Node[+T](i: T)
```

or

```
class Graph[N <: Node[T], T]
```

Reason is: mention type parameter `T` as covariant means, for instance, that `Graph[Node[String], String]` is a subtype of `Graph[Node[String], AnyRef]`, but this creates a contradiction, through `Node[String]` is not subtype of `Node[AnyRef]`, while it should according to your definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable `variant` type `T` in `Graph[N<:Node[T], +T]`, you need to enable `Node` `T` be `variant`.

```
case class Node[+T](i:T)
```

Comment: Hi I am new to scala, may I know what's the difference between T and +T? Thanks